# Multiple calculations of one model in a table

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am a new user of Mathematica and I can't figure out how to solve this problem.
I have a computation S that gives me for 10 Random Variates 10 results:

```
Xi = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 10]
Mu = -0.00644131
Sigma= 0.0562005
t = 0.1
s = 100

fnmc[s_,Mu_,Sigma_, t_,Xi_] := s  Exp[(Mu - Sigma^2/2) t + Sigma Sqrt[t ] Xi]
S = fnmc[s, Mu, Sigma, t, Xi]
```

Now I need to compute formula S 10 times - so I'll have 100 numbers in result. 
I can't find the way to do it in a TABLE. Further, I will have to sum those 10 results and calculate Mean etc. I wanted to use TABLE because of the further computation - SUM, MEAN - I thought it is the easiest "form" of results to work with....is it?

I had in mind something like:

```
Table[S(i),{i,10}]
```

but off course it multiplies S x (i). Any suggestions?

Comment: You will get answers to your future question maybe even faster at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`S(i)` multiplies `S` with `i`. `S[i]` calls function `S` with parameter `i`.

[The four kinds of bracketing in Mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/TheFourKindsOfBracketingInMathematica.html)

---

I just realized that `S` isn't a function at all, so you don't want to call it with parameter `i`. You can get the result of `S` 10 times simply by `Table[S,{10}]`, but since `Xi` is only calculated once, this will just give you 10 times the same vector. Maybe you want to do the whole calculation 10 times? That would be:

```
Table[
 (
  Xi = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 10]; 
  Mu = -0.00644131; 
  Sigma = 0.0562005;
  t = 0.1; s = 100; 
  s*Exp[(Mu - Sigma^2/2)*t + Sigma*Sqrt[t]*Xi]
 ), {10}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! About the function - I thought that when I defined "fnmc" it became a function - so when I named as "S" the function "fnmc" with specific values, I thought that "S" it is still a function... So if I would use "fnmc" (or some function) instead of the "S", would the Table look differently? Once again thanks for your reply, it helped me a lot!

Comment: If you would use `fmnc` in the `Table`, it would get called 10 times, but as long you assign `Xi` only once at the start, it will always contain the same values, so calling `fnmc` N times will still give 10 times the same vector.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a functional programming approach map ( /@ )  your function over the Xis you've created.

```
Mu = -0.00644131;
Sigma= 0.0562005;
t = 0.1;
s = 100;

(* if you wanted ten scalar random numbers, with each one used on one application of your equation  *) 
Xi = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 10];
ans = s  Exp[(Mu - Sigma^2/2) t + Sigma Sqrt[t ] #] & /@ Xi;

(* if you wanted ten 10 dimensional  random numbers, with each 10D number used on one application of your equation  *) 

Xi = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {10,10}];
ans = s  Exp[(Mu - Sigma^2/2) t + Sigma Sqrt[t ] #] & /@ Xi;
```